# jQuery each Why is this calulation applied three times?

Tags: jquery

I am looping through span tags with a price and apply a * 2 or / 2 formula to the price. Somehow this loop aplies the formula 3 times instead of 1 time.

```
$("input[name=service_amount]:radio").change(function() {
    calcPrice(this);
});

function calcPrice(context) {
    $.each($('.order_details_small_text'), function(index, value) {
        var price = parseFloat(this.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
        var newPrice = ($(context).val() == "0" ? price / 2 : price * 2);
        $(this).html('€(' + newPrice + ')');
    });
}
```

Yes. I do have three spans with the class "order_details_small_text". But still it should loop through the spans and apply the new price based on the $(this) context ony once, right?

But instead of 40 -> 20 and 20 => 10 I'm getting 40 -> 5 and 20 -> 2.5.

Comment: Maybe I don’t understand the question. … how many radio buttons do you have called `service_amount`?

Comment: Two radio buttons. It is to switch between full service or half service. So half the price remains for half the service. So if the value of radio button 0 is selected the price needs to be half. Else double the price.

Comment: Try use `$(value)` instead if `$(this)`

Comment: The `change` will fire for the radio button you’re moving off of, too. That doesn’t explain why there are three, but try checking `if (this.checked)` before calling `calcPrice`. I’d also recommend you just store the original price in a `data-price` attribute.

Comment: Seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kUTa7/

Comment: Not sure why but using the data-price attribute and working from there fixed the problem. So the replace function might have caused this strange behavior.